# Exception scrolling arraylist at second time

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem when I try to delete elements on an arrayList. I need to put some elements on other array and then delete this elements from the original array. I put the code below:

```
private void setOrderAnswers(int position) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        listAnswersAux.add(listAnswers.get((position * 4) + i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        listAnswers.remove((position * 4) + i);
    }
}
```

The error I have is an IndexOutOfBounds exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
```

I don't know why I have this exception when I try to remove this index, but when I go to the index to copy the element, there is no problem. I mean, the index is OK because I can see the element before delete it.

And I always have the exception on Index value = 10, I can do all this operations before going to index=10 (position = 2).

Can anyone helps me? Thanks a lot!

```
06-14 09:58:58.455 31337-31337/com.prodintec.am_motion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.prodintec.am_motion, PID: 31337
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prodintec.am_motion/com.prodintec.am_motion.QuizActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10
                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                         at com.prodintec.am_motion.QuizActivity.setOrderAnswers(QuizActivity.java:201)
                                                                         at com.prodintec.am_motion.QuizActivity.randomQuestions(QuizActivity.java:168)
                                                                         at com.prodintec.am_motion.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:48)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: maybe that's because you've deleted the 10th element on the first run?

Comment: @Imrik can you please tell the size of your list and what type of list are you using??

Comment: @imrik IndexOutOfBoundsException--Thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range. as per java docs.

Comment: @Imrik It would be better if you would post the full stacktrace of your exception.

Comment: @Jeeva I post the full stacktrace of my exception. I'm using string ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void setOrderAnswers(int position) {
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    listAnswersAux.add(listAnswers.get((position * 4) + i));

    listAnswers.remove((position * 4) + i);
}   

}
```

Comment: I try this and it breaks again with the same exception.

Comment: same exception beacuse your arraylist size

Comment: yes, because the index is 10 and the size is 10. But I don't know why it does the first line correctly and the second not... The index is the same.

Comment: just try one tiem to increase your arraylist size than appy this code